# Yeoman and Xcode: library not found for -lgcc_s.10.5

Tags: gcc, polymer, generator, yeoman, libraries

I'm trying to use `yo polymer` for generate a new project scaffold, and in the process of installing the dependencies i get like 7 errors and all have these two lines.

```
ld: library not found for -lgcc_s.10.5
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

What library is `-lgcc_s`?  Please some help here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`yo polymer` generated project include some dependency than need to compile for you platform, mostly `image-min`,this need three tools that write in no-js.You can remove these dependency from you `package.json`, then reinstall again.

You should paste more information about error.

The `-lgcc_s` error is tell you you don't have a full compiler env for dynamic compile dependency.

Comment: that is all that console print to me :S don't know where give you more info sorry